# moment js bug : unexpected behavior when I select new timezone

Tags: momentjs

Unexpected behavior I first select the timezone in drop-down when I press another timezone in select, the previous selected timezone are save.

```js
function run(){
  var timeZone = document.getElementById("selectTimezone");

  var i = timeZone.selectedIndex;
  var removeParenthesis = timeZone.options[i].text.replace(/[()]/g, '')
  var splitString = removeParenthesis.split(' ')
  var d = new Date('Nov 1, 2017 ' + ' ' +  splitString[0])

  var $clock = $('#clock'),
      eventTime = moment(d.getTime()).unix(),
      currentTime = moment(new Date().getTime()).unix(),
      diffTime = eventTime - currentTime,
      duration = moment.duration(diffTime * 1000, 'milliseconds'),
      interval = 1000;

  // if time to countdown
  if(diffTime > 0) {

    // Show clock
    // $clock.show();


    setInterval(function(){

      duration = moment.duration(duration.asMilliseconds() - interval, 'milliseconds');
      var d = moment.duration(duration).days(),
          h = moment.duration(duration).hours(),
          m = moment.duration(duration).minutes(),
          s = moment.duration(duration).seconds();

      d = $.trim(d).length === 1 ? '0' + d : d;
      h = $.trim(h).length === 1 ? '0' + h : h;
      m = $.trim(m).length === 1 ? '0' + m : m;
      s = $.trim(s).length === 1 ? '0' + s : s;

      // show how many hours, minutes and seconds are left
      $('.days').text(d + 'days');
      $('.hours').text(h + 'hours');
      $('.minutes').text(m + 'minutes');
      $('.seconds').text(s + 'seconds');

    }, interval);

  }  
}
```

https://codepen.io/edward1995/pen/oGpMOq

Comment: https://codepen.io/edward1995/pen/oGpMOq

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Everytime you call run() a new interval is started trying to overrwite .days, .hours, ... etc. Make sure to save the interval and cancel it before starting a new interval

Comment: how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Clear the interval before starting a new one

```
var myInterval;// Used to save previous interval if one has been started
function run(){
  var timeZone = document.getElementById("selectTimezone");

  var i = timeZone.selectedIndex;
  var removeParenthesis = timeZone.options[i].text.replace(/[()]/g, '')
  var splitString = removeParenthesis.split(' ')
  var d = new Date('Nov 1, 2017 ' + ' ' +  splitString[0])

  var $clock = $('#clock'),
      eventTime = moment(d.getTime()).unix(),
      currentTime = moment(new Date().getTime()).unix(),
      diffTime = eventTime - currentTime,
      duration = moment.duration(diffTime * 1000, 'milliseconds'),
      interval = 1000;

  // if time to countdown
  if(diffTime > 0) {

    // Show clock
    // $clock.show();

    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = setInterval(function(){

      duration = moment.duration(duration.asMilliseconds() - interval, 'milliseconds');
      var d = moment.duration(duration).days(),
          h = moment.duration(duration).hours(),
          m = moment.duration(duration).minutes(),
          s = moment.duration(duration).seconds();

      d = $.trim(d).length === 1 ? '0' + d : d;
      h = $.trim(h).length === 1 ? '0' + h : h;
      m = $.trim(m).length === 1 ? '0' + m : m;
      s = $.trim(s).length === 1 ? '0' + s : s;

      // show how many hours, minutes and seconds are left
      $('.days').text(d + 'days');
      $('.hours').text(h + 'hours');
      $('.minutes').text(m + 'minutes');
      $('.seconds').text(s + 'seconds');

    }, interval);

  }  
}
```